# Dual Juniper MX80 problem

Tags: router, redundancy, juniper-mx, stacking

We have 2x Juniper MX80 routers with only one currently being actively used. Second one is waiting to take over in the event of disaster. We also have two ISP's that deliver network to our MX80.

We want to get 2nd MX80 unit actively running, get 2nd link from each of our ISP and configure both routers for HA. We want to avoid SPoF in our environment without the need to come to DC and manually plug cables from one MX80 to another.

I would like to know if this is possible to do with MX80? How do you tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you please share connectivity for MX80 with ISP? I guess you require traffic shift from one MX80 to another MX80 in case primary link goes down due to ISP or hardware issue.

Comment: In case you want to have active back without need of someone coming to DC and plug the cable , you must have backup link up and running on second MX80.

Comment: @NABEELNASIR -> OK that is the plan. But how do you configure that?

Comment: You can use eBGP between each MX80 and ISP. Between MX80s , IBGP will be used.

Comment: do you use VCP on MX80 for setting the iBGP?

Comment: Or do you use VRRP on MC80 for setting the iBGP?